# Which is correct: "cope up", "cope with" or "cope up with"?

Tags: phrases, vocabulary

So, I was just writing an essay as part of my summer holiday homework, and I got stuck at this phrase - is it "cope up", "cope with" or "cope up with"? Naturally, cope up with sounds okay, as I have heard many people use it while speaking... but I think that cope with should be correct??

Which one should I use? If more than one is correct in different contexts, please explain the meaning of all that are correct, thanks.

Comment: By chance are you an Indian English speaker or do you live in an English speaking country? It could be that "cope up with" is used in your dialect but it is totally unfamiliar to me. In my dialect it's **cope with**

Comment: I suggest consulting two or three online dictionaries and see what they say.

Comment: Please supply the context you have in mind for this phrase. Odd turns of phrase sometimes work when given suitable context.

Comment: I believe your confusedly muddling "cope with" and "put up with," which can mean different things but have quite a bit of overlap where they're synonyms.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yeah, I study in India... however, I am pretty sure we follow British English here, so it should be "cope with"?

Comment: I did search the phrase up on Google, but there are varying results...most agree that "cope up" is incorrect, but some say "cope with" while others say "cope up with"...

Comment: Indian English has many expressions in common with BrEng but it is a well-established English dialect with its own set of rules concerning grammar and usages.

Comment: @Lawrence say in the context of studies? like "are you able to cope with the psychology syllabus" or "cope up with the syllabus" ??

Comment: I think "cope up with" is something Indians generally use because even when I search the phrase on Google, the only results it shows are related to India.... however, I needed this for my school essay, so what would be the correct statement according to British English?

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes, but I don't think I am supposed to use that according to the CBSE curriculum, not too sure though

Comment: Find me the dictionary entry which mentions "cope up with", if you can't find one then you have your answer. Try [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=cope+up+with), Webster-Merriam, [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=en_dictionary&dictionary=en&query=cope+up+with), Macmillan and Longman.

Comment: @Raghavendra Singh If you are supposed to be using standard English then "cope with" is the only option. If you are supposed to be using Indan dialect then, presumably, "cope up with" would be acceptable but it will identify you as a dialect speaker to most, if not all, speakers of other dialects of English. The words "marra" and "hinny" for "friend" and "darling" would mark North East England dialect to those familiar with them and "hood" and "bonnet" for the engine bay cover of a car would identify US and UK dialect speakers to esch other.

Comment: Could "cope up with the course" be a mistake for "keep up with the course"? I'm not an expert on Indian English, but certainly "cope with" is usual in UK and US, unless it's a specialised sense of cope e.g. coping a wall.

Comment: Thanks. Please add the sentence (which serves as context) to the question. // I echo the others’ comments that “cope with” is the only BrE option that works in that context.

Comment: One copes with a coping saw. If the line is vertical you could cope up. And if you didn’t know to use a coping saw you might be told to cope up with the coping saw.   My point is without knowing what you intend to say it’s impossible to say what’s right or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Cope up with” incorrect. You can use ‘Cope with’ to mean deal successfully with a difficult situation or job.  “Cope up” is an interpretation that is sometimes used incorrectly in place of “keep up.”